# Proper parallelization using parfor

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I have written some image processing code in Matlab I'd like to speed up using prallel processing. I picked the task that takes longest: Applying gaussian blur to the image. With the help of file exchange I have already gotten a faster gaussian blur than imfilter(). However, it will still not scale up. Here is my testing code:

```
clear all
clc
image_paths = dir('C:\pics\Baustahl\3Bleche(3)\*.png');       
image_paths = sort({image_paths.name});

count = 600;

Img = cell(1, count);
Mean = cell(1, count);

for i = 1:count
    Img{i} = imread(['C:\pics\Baustahl\3Bleche(3)\ ' image_paths{i}]);
    Img{i} = Img{i}(:,:,1);
    Img{i} = single(Img{i})./255;
end
clear vars bilder

fprintf(1, 'Starting processing....\n');

starttime = tic;
parfor (i = 1:count, 4)
    Mean{i} = imgaussian(Img{i}, 25, 81);
end
elapsedtime = toc(starttime);
fprintf(1, 'Finished processing. (%d Files in %.1fs, %.1f files/second)\n', count, elapsedtime, count/elapsedtime);
fprintf(1, '\n');

clear vars Img Mean
```

My system has a Q6600 and 4GB of RAM (which is sufficient) and if I restrict MATLAB to one core I get:

> Finished processing. (600 Files in 12.0s, 49.8 files/second)

Two cores:

> Finished processing. (600 Files in 7.5s, 80.3 files/second)

Using all four cores I get the following:

> Finished processing. (600 Files in 5.7s, 104.7 files/second)

That's a speedup by two, although the performance should quadruple. Every iteration is independent of the others, therefore this is really well suited for parallel processing. **Why does it scale so badly?**

Things I have tried:

1. I installed OpenCV and EmguCV wrapper for C#. Using a standard for-loop I get ~52 files/second, using the Parallel.ForEach() I get ~200 files/second. (As I expected)
2. Using a different amount of files. Does not change the files/second if I choose enough files:

   > 20 Files in 0.3s, 72.7 files/second
   >   60 Files in 0.6s, 94.3 files/second
   >   200 Files in 1.9s, 105.3 files/second
3. Using a normal for-loop in Matlab changes nothing. Apparently it does the same amount of parallelization (auto-magically) as the parfor-loop.
4. Explicitly specify that it should use 4 worker threads (see above) - does nothing at all. (Not even degrade performance when set to 1)

The files are approx. 640x480 grayscale and have similar contents.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened the [`matlabpool`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/matlabpool.html) before calling `parfor` (otherwise it will behave like a normal for)?

```
matlabpool 4
parfor 
    ...
end
matlabpool close
```

Be aware that there will be 10-20s of overhead for opening and closing the pool.

Comment: I just tried that (excluding the matlabpool calls from the timing of course) and it gets _slower_ to about 56 fps.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a good speedup from a simple addition to your code. As mentioned above there can actually be detrimental performance using `parfor` if you dont have enough iterations or calculations. The overhead of sending the files to the right memory space and bringing it back can cause this.

I guess you could try `spmd` and equally divide the number of images up for each worker (kind of like what `parfor` does anyway). Really not sure if `spmd` or `parfor` is faster when you can use `parfor` but its worth a shot.